# Python PostgreSQL Transaction Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to use Django's ORM to do some data processing with a PostgreSQL backend. Given a primary record, generate hundreds of records in a related table, but if any errors occur, I want to rollback all record creations. Therefore, I have the entire process wrapped in a manual transaction.

```
@transaction.commit_manually(main_record)
def save_data(data):
    try:
        create lots of records -> .save()
    except Exception, e:
        print 'Unexpected Error: %s' % e
        transaction.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        print 'Saving...'
        try:
            imgObj.processed = True
            main_record.save()
            transaction.commit()
            print 'Saved!'
        except Exception, e:
            print 'Unexpected Error during commit: %s' % e
            raise
```

However, when I try to commit(), it throws the Exception "I/O operation on closed file". Googling finds a few mentions of this, but not many in regards to PG, and no solutions. What does this mean?

Edit: I also noticed that when this happens, there's also a postgres process labeled with my database name and the status "IDLE in transaction". Should I end this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not running this on the development server, then the error is most likely from your "print" statements.  When running from Apache via mod_wsgi, for example, the stdout file descriptors are closed, so you cannot "print" as normal.

Comment: Are you saying, that the 'IDLE in transaction' processes are related to the print statements (meaning that the result from the apache module reporting errors)?